# Query when parameter is not null

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014-express

I am using sql procedure to get the data . But i have a problem like i am using ISNULL function and return empty string if it is null in such a way it works fine. But if it is not null then i have to execute a query.

```
ISNULL(uinfo.[State], '') StateText,
```

I mean if state is not null then i will get the state name according the state ID thats why i need to execute a sub query but I got a syntax error.

Comment: Please specify database you're using in tags

Comment: I am using MS Sql 2014

Comment: Please add this to question tags

Comment: Show the query with the subquery, that you have tried.

Comment: Toss us procedure how it looks and some data by any chances, that way we could help out, right now we don't have enough info to tell you anything

Comment: ISNULL((uinfo.[State], '') OR (Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = uinfo.[State]))  StateText,

Comment: Try something like `CASE WHEN uinfo.[State] is null THEN '' ELSE (SELECT DetailData FROM MasterDetails WHERE ID = uinfo.[State]) END`

Comment: Thank You So much ! It works fine   :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **case when the**

```
CASE WHEN uinfo.[State] IS NULL THEN 
         '' 
     ELSE 
        (SELECT TOP 1 DetailData FROM MasterDetails WHERE ID = uinfo.[State]) 
END
```